# MVC There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem> on Post Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selectlist

I am having issue with DropDownList in MVC,
 I can populate the Dropdownlist on HTTPGET i.e data entry page displays the Dropdown list with proper data from datatable, but as soon as I press Submit button MVC takes me on the Viewer line of DropDownList with the error "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable'  that has the key 'Suburb'"

My Model is

```
   public  class ServiceEntryRegister
{
    public List<ReceiptHeader> HEADER { get; set; }
    public List<ReceiptDetail> DETAIL { get; set; }

    public ReceiptHeader SingleHEADER { get; set; }
    public ReceiptDetail SingleDETAIL { get; set; }

}
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateNew()
    {

        ServiceEntryRegister Model = new ServiceEntryRegister();
        ViewBag.Btype = new SelectList(_er.BodyTypes, "Bodytypeid", "btype");
        ViewBag.Engine = new SelectList(_er.EngineTypes, "Enginetypeid", "Engine");
        ViewBag.Suburb = new SelectList(_er.Suburbs, "SuburbID", "SuburbName");
        ViewBag.VehicleMake = new SelectList(_er.VehicleMakes, "VehicleMakeID", "Make");

        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
//    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreateNew(ServiceEntryRegister RH)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            CreateBagForLists();
            RH.SingleHEADER.ReceiptID = _HC.PrimaryKeyGenerater();
            _er.ReceiptHeaders.Add(RH.SingleHEADER);
            _er.SaveChanges();
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

The View is :

```
<td>@Html.DropDownList("Suburb", String.Empty)</td>
```

I have also tried:

```
<td>@Html.DropDownList("Suburb", ViewBag.Suburb as SelectList)</td>
```

but all in vain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The ViewData item that has the key 'XXX' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o)

Comment: Because when you POST, `ModelState` is invalid and you return the view but have not re-assigned the `ViewBag` properties for the `SelectList` (refer the dupe for the correct way to handle this - your message is slightly different because of the awful use of `DropDownList()` instead of `DropDownListFor()`)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to avoid viewbags and use strongly type dropdown list.
In your approach you have to bind viewbags in both actions (post and get) to overcome this error.

Comment: Dear Anupam , Can you kindly provide the code to strongly bind the list view as I am new to MVC. And want to confirm that I am doing it in the right way